# How to group values of one column based on condition in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, group-by

My table has doctor ID, visit ID (one doctor can have several visits) and visit cause, it looks like this:

```
doctor_uid | visit_uid | visit_cause
11-11-11    22-22-11      1
22-22-22    44-44-22      2
11-11-11    23-23-23      1
```

I need to count all visits for each doctor, based on `visit_cause` (it should be equal `'1'`). Before I count all visits for each doctor without condition of `visit_cause`, I must have this in my query too:

```
SELECT 
   v.vra_uid, 
   COUNT(v.visit_uid) OVER (PARTITION BY v.vra_uid) AS number_of_visits
FROM visits v
```

It returns:

```
doctor_uid | number_of_visits 
    11-11-11    2     
    22-22-22    1
```

How can I count those visits, that have `visit_cause` = '1' for each doctor? so that it would look like:

```
    doctor_uid | number_of_visits | visits_with_cause_equal_1
    11-22-33    2                           2
    22-22-22    1                           0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
select v.vra_uid, COUNT(v.visit_uid) as number_of_visits , SUM(case when v.visit_cause = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as visits_with_cause_equal_1
from visits v 
group by v.vra_uid
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `CASE WHEN visit_cause = '1' THEN COUNT(*)`